# Gatsby build time error - WebpackError: TypeError: isRedirect is not a function

Tags: webpack, build, gatsby, reach-router

Ever since I tried protected routes with this on **login.js**

```
    <Router basepath="/">
            <PrivateRoute path="/edit" />
        </Router>
```

and this on **edit.js**

```
useEffect(() => {
    // ... some code here

    getEscritos();
    if (!user && location.pathname !== `/login`) {
        navigate("/login");
        return null;
    }
}, []);
```

I can no longer build it... the error was:

**the window is not defined**

Though locally it runs fine. Everything works.

Then I tried this on **gatsby-node.js** after research

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, 
actions, getConfig }) => {
if (stage === "build-html" || stage === "develop-html") {
actions.setWebpackConfig({
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /reach-router/,
        use: loaders.null(),
      },
    ],
  },
});
externals: getConfig().externals.concat(function (
  context,
  request,
  callback
) {
  const regex = /^@?firebase(\/(.+))?/;
  // exclude firebase products from being bundled, so 
  they will be loaded using require() at runtime.
  if (regex.test(request)) {
    return callback(null, "commonjs " + request); // <- 
   use commonjs!
    }
  callback();
  });
 }
```

};

and the error now is:

**WebpackError: TypeError: isRedirect is not a function**

I have no idea what to do...

Here is the [repo](https://github.com/jcgsr/jan-MeusEscritos#readme), if it's to any help.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your Firebase use and initialization inside the following condition:

```
if(typeof window !== 'undefined')
```

You have multiple instances of Firebase triggered in the SSR (Server-Side Rendering.

Applied in your [`escritos.js`](https://github.com/jcgsr/jan-MeusEscritos/blob/main/src/pages/escritos.js):

```
  if(typeof window !== 'undefined'){
    const db = getFirestore(app);
    const escritosColRef = collection(db, "escritos");
  }
```

The same applies to [`index.js` (line 31)](https://github.com/jcgsr/jan-MeusEscritos/blob/main/src/pages/index.js#L31) and so on...

The references that are inside a `useEffect` hook (with empty `deps`, `[]`) should work without the `window` condition since they are triggered on the DOM tree is loaded, so won't break the SSR. If the error persists, try also wrapping them.

Comment: I wrapped them all up as you suggested. Now the errors are: 'user is not defined', 'q is not defined' and three or four more of these errors while running locally.

Comment: The idea is not to copy-paste and pray xD. The idea, by wrapping the Firebase references with the condition, is to avoid the Firebase loading in the SSR, which was causing your issue. If in your implementation there are more variables that are loaded once Firebase is ready, they should be also added in the condition. I'd suggest, in the latest versions of Firebase (9) getting rid of `onCreateWebpackConfig` configuration until you see that is really needed.

Comment: :)))))) I'll pray nonetheless. I've already gotten ridden of the `onCreateWebpackConfig`. I'll keep trying as soon as possible. Thank you.

Comment: After much trying and praying, thanks to your help, the problem was not with firebase, but with jodit. But I applied your answer (using `onCreateWebpackConfig`, though) with jodit and it worked. Thanks.